# Once full screen on a popup panel created from a custom Chrome extension, the toolbar buttons on the left do not come up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a custom chrome extension that creates a new window upon a certain click. Once I maximize the newly created window, hovering the mouse over the left hand top corner of the screen does not bring up the three buttons (The green, yellow and red MAC buttons).

The way I have created the window is:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    type: 'detached_panel', //same behavior with popup, panel, detached_panel
    url: url,
    width: <some value>,
    height: <some value>
});
```

Anyone know what I can do to make the toolbar buttons appear in the full screen mode? I am using `Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)` on MAC (version 10.11.6), but I have seen this issue with older versions of Chrome and MAC as well.

I realize that I can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to restore the chrome window to its original size, but that is not very intuitive to the user.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug, check https://crbug.com

Comment: I added a bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654592# . However, still wondering if someone has a workaround by any chance?